# query works on MySQL, but no in PHP, why?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I need to display the results of this query :

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE PrestaCmd LIKE '% A -  CREP -  DPE - %'
```

but in PHP, this query doesn't work :s

This is my code :

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE PrestaCmd LIKE '%".$ch."%'";

echo $req; //returns : SELECT * FROM jos_projectlog_projects WHERE PrestaCmd LIKE '% A -  CREP -  DPE - %'

$results = mysql_query($req);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

I think the problem is coming from the '$ch' variable.
But when I put an echo of the query, it's correct, and when I put a query like this :

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM jos_projectlog_projects WHERE PrestaCmd LIKE '% A -  CREP -  DPE - %'";

echo $req; 
$results = mysql_query($req);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

it works :s

Comment: Please show the echoed query.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: please change `$results = mysql_query($req);` to `$results = mysql_query($req) or die( mysql_error() );`. If it dies and you get an error post it here.

Comment: redFilter : No datas are displayed

Comment: well it's some mistype. just compare both manual and variable queries. if you think the problem is coming from the '$ch' - double check it

Comment: I found the problem : I have &#160; to make spaces. How to convert it ?

Comment: i noticed that your table has jos_ prefix, is it within Joomla framework?

Comment: just do not convert spaces to &#160;

Comment: I need to have two spaces into the query. How to replace &#160; by a blank space ?

Answer (score 1):

@Bahumat100, if you think you have `&#160;` to make space which is causing problem, then use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) and do it like this:

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE PrestaCmd LIKE '%".html_entity_decode($ch)."%'";
```

Comment: @Col. yes I completely agree but what if the `$ch` variable is coming from somewhere (some other function / file) which is not easily changeable. In that case this would be an easy fix.

Comment: But I just use str_replace : $ch2 = str_replace("&#160;"," ",$ch); and it works.